# Check, whether variables have the same value

Tags: variables, comparison, conditional-statements

What's the simpliest way to implement a function that returns true if the variables I give it as inputs have the same value?

This is the implementation I do for 4 variables, but not sure if it works: (pseudocode)

`if var1 == var2 and var2 == var3 and var3 == var4 then return true`

Should I use condition within condition maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yea so it would look like

```
if (var1 == var2 && var2==var3 && var3==var4) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

or

```
if (var1 == var2 && var1==var3 && var1==var4) {
    return true;
}
```

etc

Comment: Are the two versions surely the same? I have doubts with the second solution. I mean, in the first one, we go around and it provides that all of them are the same. But in the second one, we compare only to the first element.

A bit hard to explain, maybe because of my instincts, I had doubts in that.

Comment: yea it's the same.  If you look at the logic, if a=b and a=c, then b=c